# $.ajax will not work with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have the following code which I am try to write with coffeescript.

```
$.ajax {
  type: 'GET'
  url: '/dashboard'
  success: (response) -> 
    $('.loading_row').remove()
  dataType: 'script'
}
```

Every time I try to run this get the following error message:

`Assertion failed: (0 && "implement me"), function uv_fs_readlink, file src/unix/fs.c, line 613.`

I can solve this by putting the success callback all on one line but I wish to call multiple methods in the callback so this will not work.

```
$.ajax {
  type: 'GET'
  url: '/dashboard'
  success: (response) -> $('.loading_row').remove()
  dataType: 'script'
}
```

Comment: You'll have to set this up a bit more... this looks like jQuery, but the error you're getting is from a `c` file. So you're running this under Node.js, right? Using `$ = require 'jquery'` And you're using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) so that the `.remove()` line is meaningful?

Comment: It's running under Rails 3.1, jquery has been included and other jquery lines in the file work fine. Not using jsdom.

Comment: OK... so you're seeing this error at compile-time? It may be a problem with the JavaScript environment ExecJS is using, then. Try adding `therubyracer` to your Gemfile and running `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be the case that you're getting different results depending on whether the success callback is defined on one line or indented. Both the code snippets you give compile to the exact same JavaScript, byte for byte:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/dashboard',
  success: function(response) {
    return $('.loading_row').remove();
  },
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Unless perhaps you're using an older version of CoffeeScript? The latest release is 1.1.2.

Comment: coffee-rails gem in Rails 3.1 so I assume that this is using the latest version of coffeescript.